# mhchem exponent - missing

Tags: beamer, chemistry, mhchem

I want to write the following formula: SeO_4^(2-). When I write it as suggested in the documentation of the LATEX package then the formula is worng and doubled and when I write it with extra brackets, the minus sign in the exponent goes missing... what did I do wrong?

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\ce{SeO4^2−} % Documentation for the LATEX Packages -> formula wrong and doubled
\ce{SeO4^{2−}} % my solution -> minus missing
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I try to compile your code as it is, I get the following error messaged: `Package mhchem Error: Assertion failed: ` and `Package inputenc Error: Unicode character − (U+2212)`.

Comment: If I replace `−` with `-`, the code works perfectly fine: `\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\ce{SeO4^2-}
\end{frame}
\end{document}`.

Comment: @leandriis, solution in your comment doesn't work. Missed is frame's option `fragile`. Please consider to write an answer instead just a comment.

Comment: @Zarko: I have added an answer. On my sytem with the recent versions of `beamer` and `mhchem`,  the example works just fine even without the `fragile` option

Comment: @leandriis, indeed! I just update my MikTeX installation and now it works! +1 for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Upon compiling your document, one recieves the following error messages:

```
Package mhchem Error: Assertion failed: Unexpected input character.

Package inputenc Error: Unicode character − (U+2212) (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

These error messages are generated because of the use of `−` instead of `-`. Thus, replacing `−` with `-` in your code will result in the correct output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer} 
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame} 
\ce{SeO4^2-} 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```